# Implementation of PHP conversion script

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to implement a [PHP script](https://gist.github.com/chappy84/8d23f9c3235796dec46ea0749c15d83f) that converts a .stravactivity file to GPX - it's using github code, what's the best way to handle a file and pass in to variable $filename

Getting this error when I try to open through cli:

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear: the php script you point to actually accepts a filename, via the command line (it's a cli script in case you didn't notice)

Comment: @fvu that's what I'm looking to do - could you point me in the right direction to passing filenames through command line please?

Comment: just calling it as `/path/to/convert_stravactivity_to_gpx /path/to/the/file.stravactivity` should do the trick

Comment: it would seem I get an fopen(): error when importing - appreciate your help @fvu - apologies for lack of clarification,

Comment: Ah, okay :) Give me a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by this part of the code:

```
$pwd = $_SERVER['PWD'];
$filePath = realpath($pwd . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
if (false === ($fh = fopen($filePath, 'r'))) {
    die('Couldnt open ' . $filename);
}
```

Which I guess serves the author's purposes but is quite odd: it builds a path out of the directory in which the script lives and whatever gets passed in $argv[1]. As you already pass a full path to the file in $argv[1] that doesn't work. Very quick fix might be

```
//$pwd = $_SERVER['PWD'];
$filePath = $argv[1];
if (false === ($fh = fopen($filePath, 'r'))) {
    die('Couldnt open ' . $filename);
}
```

that is, using the value passed in $argv[1] "as is". Obviously this also would allow you to simplify the code above but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.